# What is best way to transfer the file to other server other than socket connection

Tags: file-transfer

I want to transfer fle from one server to other server.What are different ways to transfer the file to other server other than **Socket connection**? and  Which is best way to transfer the file?

Thank you.

Comment: There's always tapes or CDs and DHL/UPS/your local postal service. Why are you excluding sockets?

Comment: There are also Hollerith cards (don't drop the deck); paper tape (don't tear it); 7 track tape and 9 track tape (don't get them mixed up); streaming tape cartridges; disk cartridges (not on the London Underground); floppy discs; diskettes; Zip drives; truckloads of CDs, DVD-RAMs, or DVD-ROMs; 75baud modems, 56kB modems; NVRAM; ROM; ... Not a real question.

Comment: @Mat I just want to know the different kind of way and most reliable way to transfer the files.

Comment: @Qazi: there is no such thing as a "best way". Look at your requirements and find an existing tool that meets them. There are tons out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can just copy the file to a shared folder. It's a known EIP integration style, see http://www.eaipatterns.com/toc.html. Interestingly, this way you can also make it available to many servers at once, kind of publishing.

Comment: But the backend of the shared folder would be based on sockets. :)

Comment: @NabilA. No. It could be based on native NetBIOS for example, or IPX.

Comment: @Nabil there may be several EE servers or several virtual machines running on the same computer, then there will be no network involved

Comment: Ok, got me. I should have wrote could instead of would.

Comment: Pls suggest me the best way or ll  i go with socket connection?

Comment: If you want it synchroneous there is no other way but TCP, otherwise you may consider a shared folder. Like I said it's a legal Enterprise Integration Pattern.